# Execute pdflatex program via Python

Tags: python, shell, latex

I have two Python variables: `name` and `filename`. If I assign them with values like

```
name = "HELLO"
```

and

```
filename = "demo.tex"
```

How can I write a Python script so that it can run the following shell command:

```
pdflatex "\def\name{HELLO} \input demo.tex"
```

Since I need to compile many tex files so I need this kind of method to automate the process.

A minimal tex file

```tex
% demo.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\name
\end{document}
```

Python script:

```
import subprocess
name = "HELLO"
filename = "demo.tex"
subprocess.run(["pdflatex", "\\def\\name{{name}} \\input {filename}"])
```

I want `{name}` and `{filename}` to be replaced by `HELLO` and `demo.tex`.

**Update**:
By the hint of @Klaus D., I finally solved this problem:

```py
subprocess.run(["pdflatex", "\\def\\name{", f"{name}", "}", f"\\input {filename}"])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I have uploaded my code@KlausD.

Comment: Your second part of the string is not OK. if you want to use f-string formatting, you have to prefix the string with `f`. Please note that using `{` is tricky, it has to be doubles. Also watch out for possible injections.

Comment: There is another problem. Using the updated code, it seems that the `\def` part will be converted to `\def\name{ HELLO }` with two space characters around `HELLO`. How can I remove them? @KlausD.

Answer (score 0):

To run shell command in python you could use `subprocess` module from python.

Here's an example of `subprocess`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('echo "hello world"')
```

You can replace `echo "hello world"` with your command